# C Value of initialised variable changes by itself after comparison

Tags: c

I am implementing a simple tree structure in C. The program showed some strange behaviour, and I was able to narrow it down to a place, where value stored in a memory location and accessed by using pointers unexpectedly changes. It is replicable, but only happens after a few runs (depending deterministically on the input) of a recursive function. It is in somewhere in the header of 'while' statement. I have checked that just before 'while' all pointers point to memory cells that have expected, well-defined etc. content. What bugs me most, is that even if I assign copy of the value to another variable that variable changes too. I have no idea how it is possible, though I suspect there's something obvious I'm missing. Below are relevant code fragments.

```
typedef struct _Node {
    int root;
    struct _Node *children;
    struct _Node *next;
    struct _Node *previous;
} Node;

int delete_subtree_aux(Node *n) {

    Node *children = get_children(n);

    int i = children->root;
    int j = i;

    // At this point i and j both equal e.g. -4

    while (!(children->next->root == children->root)) {

        i = children->root; 

        // At this point i equals -3

        assert(i == j);

        // And j equals -3 too!

        delete_subtree_aux(get_first(children));

    }

    free_node(children);
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

After setting additional breakpoint at `free_node(children);` I have noticed that something is off with the order of instructions executed. At one time program goes straight from `free_node(children);` to the inside of the loop bypassing `while` condition checking. 'n', 'i', 'j' and 'children' change together and correspond to different function inputs. Setting data breakpoints revealed that different 'j's are at two different memory addresses.

It seems to me, like for some reason that a few instances of this function are somehow executed in paralell, but that's not my intention. My follow-up question is, can freeing memory in such conditions cause errors? If yes, what should I do to fix it?

Edit 2:
Source for other functions called in the code above:

```
int free_node(Node *n) {
    free(n);
}

Node *get_children(Node *n) {
    return n->children;
}

Node *get_first(Node *list) {
    return list->next;
}
```

Comment: Run your program under debugger and set a watchpoint associated with the variable `j`. The debugger will stop the program at the moment the value of `j` changes. At least you will see which line of the program is responsible for the change, and I bet it's not the `assert`.

Comment: of course it's not assert. As I said earlier, the line that changes j is the header of while statement (so `while (!(children->next->root == children->root)) { `)

Comment: It's probably not that line, either. So, run the debugger.

Comment: Is it possible for the `children` pointer to point to garbage data?

Comment: No, it points to a proper struct _Node, but its values do change, its root changes just like i and j, and 'next' and previous pointers before 'while' point to children itself, and after 'while' they point to completely different Node that is stored in an array (the array is accesible in this scope though)

Comment: Because your `delete_subtree_aux` is recursive I don't think you viewed the `j` as you expected in debugger. Please check your `j` holds -4 and holds -3 has the same ADDRESS or not.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I think you viewed the different LEVEL of the `delete_subtree_aux` function so there is no problem in fact.  At recursion, your function has multiple call stacks. Is the final result wrong?

Comment: Well, just after this "weird behaviour" in execution of the program it tries to get_children() of a node and gets a Node that is garbage (the 'root' is 0, while all nodes from get_children() should have negative root)

Comment: I think the problem is the `get_first`'s logic. Can you post all source ? Includes how the tree is constructed.

Comment: get_first is just return n->next; (I implemented list as a Node, with next pointing to first node, and previous pointing to the last one) (get_children returns such list; every list has negative root, while regular nodes have positive roots)

Comment: Updated the question with the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when `get_first(children) == get_last(children)`  the while loop should have its last iteration. However, `delete_subtree_aux` fails to update where `children->next` points to. When `children` of the node at this address are free'd, the while loop instead of stopping, tries to do one more iteration (since `children->next` points to some `Node`-like garbage in memory that is different to `children`). This time however, it tries to access free'd `children`, and that of course causes error.

The mysterious changing of 'i', 'j', 'children', and 'n' between before `while` and inside were a result of viewing different levels of recursive function on the stack, as pointed out by @Holsety in the comments.